# Batch file. What is -dir in this context doing? Trying to do the same in Shell

Tags: shell, batch-file, parameters

I'm trying to call the same perl script, that is called by the below batch file, in my shell script.  I'm getting argument errors.  What is -dir?

```
 @ECHO OFF
 ECHO.
 perl C:\tools\script.pl -dir "%CD%"
```

I am doing something like

```
 for d in */ ; do
 cd $d
 perl c:/tools/script.pl $d $d
 cd ..
 done
```

Comment: `-dir` is probably just an argument to the script.

Comment: tried passing it in as a string and as the directory as I have above.  Neither work.  Figured it must be a batch thing.

Comment: The `-dir` is almost certainly something that is being processed inside the `script.pl`. Can you read that code and see what is happening with the argument processing? And did you try (in unix) `perl script.pl -dir "$PWD"`? (or `--dir` possibly). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're used to shell scripting in Unix, not Windows.  for loops work differently on Windows; you probably want something like this.

```
for /d %%i in (*) do (
    cd %%i
    perl C:\tools\script.pl -dir %%i
    cd ..
)
```

Here's some [documentation](http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html) for the for loop for directories.  The `/d` option makes the for loop only look at directories; variables in batch scripts use `%%k` (where `k` is a letter) for variable names instead of `$k` like bash.

It seems most likely that `-dir` is just an option that you give the script; it's specific to your actual Perl script, not batch scripts.

Comment: Sorry I was trying to convert the simple batch script into my looping shell script.  The looping is just what I've added.